# How do I link an email from a webpage to mu4e?

Tags: email, mu4e, linux

So when I press a link in, for example firefox, it open Emacs mu4e "Compose email" with the receiver attached.

I’m on Linux.

Comment: There is a related discussion here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mu-discuss/Uce5fTro9gU/ib0-of5ycPwJ from some time ago. Might be of some help.